# Normal Maps can I create my own or download it?

Tags: normal-map

How I can download or create my own what is normal map can we edit in Gimp or Photoshop ?

Comment: There are several ways, you can for example bake it from a high poly model which is covered in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw or you can use some normal map generator like CrazyBump or some non-commercial alternatives. But I am sure you can find some already made by searching the internet for "free normal maps" :)

Comment: I seen this video after seen I upload question

Comment: So you should then know how to create a normal map in Blender. What specific problem do you have with that?

Comment: It's nothing but a jpg images? Are normal Maps?

Comment: Yes, it is just a specially colored image. For the start, you can try this free generator: http://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/, download a map and try to apply it to your model to see how it works.

Comment: I seen I can import plug in for Gimp I use Gimp so I choose and I will today definitely try this jpg file hmm ok thanks

Comment: Woh link is very useful automatically generated normal map so nice

Comment: Only one time it genrat? Second time it doesn't work?